# Flying with domestic with ID that expires on the trip

Tags: usa

I live in Texas and I'm 17. A lot of my family and friends live in California. For my 18th birthday my family planned a trip to California. The problem is my license expires on my 18th birthday while I'll be in California, and with Texas I can't apply for my normal license until my 18th birthday or afterwards.

So since I'm turning 18 while on my trip and my only real form of ID will expire during it, will I have problems on my return flight using a recently expired ID? Will having my birth certificate, social security card, and diploma help?

Thanks for any answers you can provide!

Comment: You could always get a passport, if you need a workaround.  This would also let you visit Mexico, Canada, etc.  (Lots of good flights from some Texas airports to Calgary, Toronto, ...)